# How do I get up and running in Visual Studio 2017 with TypeScript and Vue.js?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to make **vue.js** and **typescript** working together. But when I compile the vue source code i've got "**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**" at my index.html.

Here's what I did:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"noImplicitAny": false,
"noEmitOnError": true,
"removeComments": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"lib": [
  "dom",
  "es5",
  "es2015.promise"
]
},
"include": [
  "scripts/**/*"
],
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "wwwroot"
],
"compileOnSave": true
}
```

**scripts/test.ts** (it's from vue.js [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components/))

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
// The @Component decorator indicates the class is a Vue component
@Component({
  // All component options are allowed in here
  template: '<button @click="onClick">Click!</button>'
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  // Initial data can be declared as instance properties
  message: string = 'Hello!'
  // Component methods can be declared as instance methods
  onClick(): void {
    window.alert(this.message)
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.2.6",
  "vue-router": "^2.4.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "vue-class-component": "^5.0.1"
}
```

I'm not using node.js (and I don't want to), only npm to download dependencies. I'm also working in Visual Studio 2017 and the application is running on .net core server.

Comment: It looks like you're missing requirejs and an app setup file. When you run the application and look at the compiled code you'll see your imports are generating require(...) commands. I've have to add the script reference for require and set the data-main to a single ts file which sets up the require code supporting the TS generated code. Did you need a specific example of this?

Comment: @Laston, did you ever get this working.  I too am trying to get Vue, VS 2017 and TS working together.  In my case, without using SPA.